# Signal value 1 goes to Weak high H in vhdl for std_logic type

Tags: flash, memory, vhdl

I am facing a problem in designing a NOR flash controller. I have used simulation model of a Micron NOR flash to verify controller design. The issue is a signal coming out from flash sim model is set to logic 1 but when the same signal mapped to an input signal of type std_logic in my controller, it is showing 'H' in modelsim simulator. I have not used any interface between the controller top and flash sim model instead direct port connection is done in VHDL. Can anybody please help here?

Comment: to_01 or to_01xz functions could be useful.

Answer (score 0):

How is the signal mapped to your input signal? If you only care about a 1 or a 0, you could use a case statement like so:

```
case (fromFlashSimModel) is
    when 'H' | when 'Z' =>
         -- map from those
    when '1' =>
         -- etc
    when others =>
end case;
```